# Best way to send SQL T-Logs to EC2 Instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm going to use an EC2 instance for DR purposes of my SQL 2008 server. My plan is to ship the transaction logs for ~500 databases up to AWS and then restore them to an EC2 instance running SQL.

I'm going to be using a PowerShell script on each side (1 to send the T-Logs to Amazon, another to restore them).

I'm trying to decide if I should ship them directly to EC2 or ship them to S3. My thoughts on using S3 were that it would always be available and allow me to take down the EC2 instance without disrupting the transfer of the files to Amazon.

Any thoughts on the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**S3**

You have the right idea. S3 is permanent, easy to push to and fetch from. S3 has many uses but this is most defiantly one of them.

using an EC2 instance for this would be possible, but would really not be worth it, and you would probably want to store in S3 anyway rather than EBS.